# express-validator 4 not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-validator

Im trying to use `express-validator v4.3.0` to validate inputs to validate express inputs. I tried to follow the documentation but can't get it to work... It's not detecting any errors. Also it stalls in the route. I guess I'm missing the `next()` function call. What am I missing?

This is my route:

```
routes.get(
  "/localizations/apps/:app_name/locales/:locale_abbr_short",
  validateParams,
  fetchLocalization,
)
```

This is `validateParams`:

```
export async function validateParams() {
  const allowedAppNames = ['common','webcalc_v2']
  const allowedLocales= ['dk']

  return [
    check('app_name').isIn(allowedAppNames).withMessage('App name is unknown').trim(),
    check('locale_abbr_short').isIn(allowedLocales).withMessage('Locale is unknown').trim(),
    check('provider').isNumeric().withMessage('Provider id must be a number').trim(),
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `validateParams` function in order to return an array of validation middlewares:

```
routes.get(
    "/localizations/apps/:app_name/locales/:locale_abbr_short",
    validateParams(),
    fetchLocalization,
)
```

Comment: I get this typescript error:

error TS2345: Argument of type 'Promise<ValidationChain[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams'.
  Type 'Promise<ValidationChain[]>' is not assignable to type '(RequestHandler | ErrorRequestHandler)[]'.
    Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Promise<ValidationChain[]>'.

Comment: Try to remove async keyword when you export validation function